# TFS file icons in Visual Studio 2013 are not updated

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a straight-forward solution in VS2013 with a couple of projects, folders and files added. The solution is added to source-control (Team Foundation Server) and everything works fine in regards to checking out files, comparing versions, resolving conflicts and checking in. But no matter what I do the small icons next to the files, folders, projects and solution are never updated. E.g. when I check out a particular file the icon is still that of a checked in file, even though the tool tip shows text for the checked out icon.

I can certainly live with this but I just wonder if anyone has seen it before?

Comment: This is happening only for that specific solution?

Comment: No this happens on all solutions in TFS